# Как сделать чтобы бот проверил свое же сообщение и если оно верно выдал результат?

Tags: python

Создаю чат бота для подбора техники и после теста у меня выдается результат который нужно сравнить с заготовленным и если он верен, отправить другие сообщения.

Вот код теста

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Стоит сначала основы питона изучить, а потом уже ботов писать, полагаю.

Comment: согласен, я новичок в нем, мало что понимаю

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю из кода, нечто заготовленное нужно сравнивать с элементами из списка `answers`. Если нужно проверить, есть ли это нечто заготовленное в списке, то можно воспользоваться следующей конструкцией:

```py
value = 'something'
answers = [a, b, c, v]
if value in answers:
   do smth
else:
   do smth
```

если значение `value` будет в списке `answers` это конструкция вернет `True` и произойдет выполнение кода в ней, если же значения в списке не будет, то конструкция вернет `False` и выполнится фрагмент кода из `else`

Если же речь идёт конкретно о сообщении бота, то:

```py
if message.text == smth:
   do smth
else:
   do smth
```